# What Kind of Pan is This?

Tags: equipment, pan

This is a screen-shot of "Chopped", a show on the Food Network that I watch a lot. Most of the pans on the show are stainless steel, but it seems that these pans are always the ones the chefs grab when I would grab Teflon. They don't seem as non-stick as Teflon, eggs especially seem to stick to these pans, the show doesn't seem to have any Teflon pans. What surface is this?

[image: 1]

Comment: Lol. +1 for butter and herb basted bacon-wrapped hotdogs. Oh Chopped.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald It's even worse than you know. The hot dogs are vegan! :)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The cookware used is by Zwilling JA Henckels. They are Thermolon-coated, which is why I mistook it for a Green Pan--they are the same coating (ceramic.)

You can see the cookware used in the show here:

http://shop.foodnetworkstore.com/nav/department/cookware/show/chopped/0

**My original guesstimation:**

This looks like a Green Pan, an attempt to make an alternative type of non-stick pan (does not use PFOA to create PTFE [Teflon])

They use ceramic to try to re-create a non-stick-ish feeling, but they definitely are not as non-stick as PTFE pans are.

http://www.green-pan.com.au/en/technology-3592.htm

I could be wrong, but I haven't seen any other pans with that colour of surface, so I'm pretty sure it's a Green Pan.

[image: GreenPan image]

Comment: AHA! That would be it. The chefs can bring their own knives, I wonder if they can bring their own pan too? I'm pretty sure I'd prefer Teflon if I wanted to fry eggs.

Comment: Teflon isn't so great for people, when the material flakes or leaches into food, so that's why there are these kinds of safe alternatives :)

Comment: Yeah, but nothing works as well for eggs! I've never had a problem with Teflon, but I know that some people avoid it like the plague.

Comment: @setek and chances of that are miniscule, plus the amount you'd have to be exposed to is far larger than you'd get from even a lot of meals cooked in that pan.

Comment: Teflon only flakes when exposed to severely high heat...eggs should be cooked at medium heat (by 'stove top' standards). 
Using Teflon for eggs is perfectly safe.

Comment: Newer coatings are, IMO, as usable as Teflon, and more durable and not as susceptible to high heat destruction.  I scoffed at Teflon scares at fist, but it is now considered enough of a carcinogen after exposure to high heat that I now actively avoid it.  And who among us never burns or overheats a pan?

Comment: @dlb my original Green Pan wasn't great at being non-stick. However, I recently picked up a RACO ceramic pan and was very (happily) surprised to find that its non-stick properties were pretty close to teflon/PTFE, if not the same!